# Are there functions (or category of functions) that satisfy following conditions?

Tags: functions, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

Are there functions(or category of functions) *S* and *U* such that

*$S(T(U(k))) = T(k)$* for any function *T* where

*$S(T(U(k))) \neq U(T(S(k)))$* and, *S* and *U* are not identity functions i.e *$S(x) \neq x$* and *$U(x) \neq x$*.

Comment: Is $S\circ T\circ U=T$ supposed to hold for all $T$ such that $S\circ T\circ U\neq U\circ T\circ S$, or just one such $T$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Ideally for all _T_, but is there a solution for just one _T_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Assume that $S(x) \ne x$ for some specific value $x$, and take $T$ to be the constant function $T \equiv x$